# Localize "loadingDialog" string in config.xml for Cordova / PhoneGap Android app

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, cordova

On the startup of my application I would like to localize the *loadingDialog* string for different languages. My application uses Phonegap/Cordova and uses the *loadingDialog* preference in *config.xml* to show an loader on startup. (Documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_project-settings_android_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20Android).)

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.app" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value="Loading"/>
    <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0x00000000" />
    [...]
    <name>App name</name>
    <description></description>
    <author email="author@mail.com" href="http://www.website.com">Author</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

In the */res/* directory I have added 10 languages, including */values/*, */values-de/* and */values/fr/* and each folder contains a *strings.xml* document with the following information.

**Strings.xml** (multiple files)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App name</string>
    <string name="loading">Loading</string>
</resources>
```

Now I would like to localize the "*Loading*" string in *config.xml* for all languages. I have tried to use the code below, but it simply display's "*@string/app_name*" as the loading message. Is it possible to localize this string on startup, and if so how?

```
<preference name="LoadingDialog" value="@string/loading"/>
```

Loading message with this setting:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, but try `android:defaultValue="@string/loading"` instead of value.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunally I get the error "_/res/xml/config.xml:5: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix_" when I am using `<preference name="LoadingDialog" android:defaultValue="@string/loading" />`

Comment: Please post back if you solve this. I would like to do the same with the `<name>` tag.

Comment: Hi JBCP. I still haven't found an answer. I have given up on it. If someone knows the answer, please tell us.